# JDBC Realm проблема с соединением, переустановка рут пароля в MySql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, cmd, jdbc

[Mysql doc, пункт 6
!](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

- Следую MySql установки по документации.

  Установил root пароль с помощью  **MySQL Installation Wizard**. Тот пароль, который я пишу в `Tomcat Realm server.xml.`
  При входе через MySql Workbench на свой connection все нормально, но при попытке получить доступ через Realm настройку JDBC Connector по тому же паролю, вызывает ошибку. [Из этого источника тоже не помогает](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68482)
- Выполняю MySql 3 и 6 пункты по документации. В конце после выполнения программы получаю в cmd: Дал пример ошибки внизу!
- В чём может быть проблема ? Я уже без вариантов,буду рад помощи!

  **C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqld.exe --default-file="my.ini" --init-file="C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\mysql-init.txt" --console**

  *2016-08-01T20:44:58.017811Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.*

  *Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).*

  *2016-08-01T20:44:58.017811Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.*

  *2016-08-01T20:44:58.018799Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 7408 ...*

  *2016-08-01T20:44:58.045232Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure.
  Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'*

*mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-08-01T20:44:59.335246Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-08-01T20:44:59.349387Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-file=my.ini'
2016-08-01T20:44:59.351372Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting*

==================================================================

> > **java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root;password=plemia000'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
> >         at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:663)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:726)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:249)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
> >         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coupon_system?user=root;password=plemia000"
      userTable="user" userNameCol="nickname" userCredCol="password"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root;password=plemia000'@'localhost'
```

означает, что у вас вместо 'root' пользователем считается 'root;password=plemia000'. В `<Realm ... >` замените строку

```
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coupon_system?user=root;password=plemia000"
```

на аналогичную, в которой точка с запятой заменена амперсандом, чтобы DNS стал корректным

```
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coupon_system?user=root&password=plemia000"
```

Comment: Пошол по твоему совету и получил : Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
The reference to entity "password" must end with the ';' delimiter.