# Переустановка root пароля в MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, cmd

Более полный вопрос, часть которого было заданно: [Часть темы тут!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550910/jdbc-realm-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2-mysql)

Попробрвал все варианты, пример:

**1.mysql-init.txt - > *содержит:* UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('pl00000') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

**2. mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server5.7\my.ini" --init-file=C:\Users\Maks1988\Desktop\mysql-init.txt**

> > mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini 
> >     mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!

**3.mysqld GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pl00000' WITH GRANT OPTION;FLUSH PRIVILEGES; Не помогает!**

**4.C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqld.exe --default-file="my.ini" --init-file="C:\Users\Maks\Desktop\mysql-init.txt" --console**

> > 2016-08-01T22:37:56.684944Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:56.684944Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:56.684944Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 2716 ...
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:56.869061Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. 
> >     Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. 
> >     The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:57.927220Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\ib_buffer_pool
> >     mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:57.942217Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 160802  1:37:57
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:57.951790Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:57.968790Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-file=my.ini'
> >     2016-08-01T22:37:57.974791Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

**5.mysql.exe --init-file=C:\Users\Maks1988\Desktop\mysql-init.txt**

> > mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'init-file=C:\Users\Maks1988\Desktop\mysql-init.txt'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Буду рад любой помоши!
- Другой сценарий, та же ошибка (**java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**)
- SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');FLUSH PRIVILEGES; Данная строка позволяет изменить пароль, для входа через cmd в mysql, но при попытке подсоединится с таким же паролем через Realm JDBC получаю ошибку! 
  *java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*
- **Скоро застрелюсь! В чём может быть еще проблема ?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coupon_system"
      connectionName="user=root" connectionPassword="password=Maks1988"
      userTable="user" userNameCol="nickname" userCredCol="password"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>

   </Realm>
```

Comment: А почему на изображении файла называется my-ini, а не my.ini?

Comment: Переименовал! Спасибо. Не помогает

Comment: Первый раз вижу такую инструкцию по работе. Где остановка сервера, где запуск с пропуском таблицы пользователей для сброса. Вход в оболочку с пустым паролем. http://ashep.org/2010/sbros-parolya-root-v-mysql/ как пример того что должно быть. Для виндовс http://www.zonepc.ru/sbros-parolya-mysql-pod-windows/

Comment: @Igor: Не имею в папке данного файла mysqld-nt.exe!

Comment: @Igor : Я использовал эту команду - > SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'); Та же логика ?

Comment: так текущий пароль знаете, не обратил внимание. Тогда просто выбрать базу, USE mysql; после поставить пароль UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User=’root’; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

выбрали базу, поставили пароль, перезагрузили привелегии

Comment: Та же ошибка при попытке конекта через JDBC Realm,(код) которого сверху.  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2):

Если забыли `Root` пароль от `MySQL`, и хотите удалить его, я знаю один рабочий метод. Только есть один минус, твоих баз данных не будет там..

1. Это деинсталировать MySQL Server
2. удалить все содержимое папки C:/ProgramData/MySQL
3. Затем снова переустановить MySQL Server

Далее там потребуют `ROOT` пароль при установки, и советую записать на бумажку что ли.. чтобы потом не забыть.

Comment: Давай попробую. Насчёт рут пароля я помню всё нормально. Я же написал что через shell получается заходить, а через JDBBC Realm кидает ошибку, с тем же паролем!

Comment: C:/ProgramData/MySQL у меня нету такой папки!

Comment: Данная папка бывает скрытой)

Comment: @Maks.Burkov вбей его в проводник) и все)

Comment: @Maks.Burkov что именно? Скрытую папку сделать видимой не умеете?

Comment: Все нормально. Ответил на вопрос раньше чем ты написал!СПС попробую так!!

Comment: Чтобы видеть скрытые файлы и папки то вот как это сделать:
*`Панель управления-->Параметры папок-->Вид-->Найдите Показывать скрытые файлы и папки-->Применить`*